# What happens when we press "execute" in eclipse or "run" in IDEA InteliJ?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, intellij-idea, build

I'd like to customize what happens when we execute or run an android application. Currently it seems to upload the apk to a temporary location on the device, and then execute

```
      pm install -r <temp_apk_path>
```

I'd like to change these options, like using `installd` always, or specifying `-d` flag to allow version downgrade. Can this be set somewhere so that it executes these commands everytime ? I can make it work with an ant build script, by making changes to the `<sdk>/tools/ant/build.xml`, but I'd then have to run ant build everytime. Is there a way to make it the IDE default ?

Bonus : I researched extensively, and didn't find a way to change the install location in the device directly, but if there is a way, please tell. What I mean is not changing the target to SD card by specifying target as [2], but the actual path, like say `data\my_own_path`

Comment: You can always run your custom Ant build script automatically from Eclipse. Go to project Properties -> Builders and import your build script. Then select Edit and in Targets Tab set which targets should be run in which build phase.

Comment: There are only 4 build phases that are mentioned in the targets. After-clean, manual-buils,auto-build, and during-clean. I'd like to change the install/deploy phase, not just the build phases. How can I do that ?

Comment: Well to customize install/deploy phase we would need a possibility to specify commands/parameters with which Eclipse starts adb. I can't see any way of doing that. However I see another way. You can specify External Tool in Eclipse which would be a script calling Ant build script and then deploying and installing apk through adb with whatever commands and parameters you like. This way we have to completely abandon Eclipse run but we can reach want you want. And External Tool can be easily start from Eclipse IDE.

Comment: That is no more than running an ant build on my own. Thanks for all the help anyway.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Unfortunately this seems the only way to go. To gain more control over deploy/install phase you could change build system to Gradle (and perhaps IDE to Android Studio). Then it's as simple as modyfing Gradle's task.

Comment: Ya, I've been trying to use that too. But my project is HUGE, and idea and studio aren't really handling them very well. In the latest builds, dex.huge property, isn't being handled at all in Idea. I'm stuck with Eclipse for now.